# Scala RAD tools

Tags: scala, rad

I am trying out on some application with Scala. I have been troubled a lot by its Swing support. Having to write the code seems to be painful. I love Netbeans Matisse function in this case.

Is there any Scala RAD tools available?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any Scala RAD tools available?

No (as far as I know).

> Having to write the code seems to be painful.

It really shouldn't be, with something like [XScalaWT](http://www.coconut-palm-software.com/the_new_visual_editor/doku.php?id=blog:simplifying_swt_with_scala). Unfortunately, I don't know if there is a Swing equivalent.

> I love Netbeans Matisse function in this case.

You can generate Java classes using Matisse and extend them in Scala.

Comment: Thanks. I am looking for some RAD tools. Google it but doesn't found an interesting result so I think they are still yet to come. Thanks for the XScalaWT anyway. There is a Swing wrapper for Scala supported by the Scala team but with poor documentation. That's why I am wondering for a RAD tools. :)